WebGL Support - Switch Option Control Not Switching Color
I am trying to get the menu box on this code to change color using webgl. For some reason I cannot get the color to change properly. The html, initShaders.js, and utility.js is already created.
Please see my .js below:
    "use strict";

    var gl;

    var theta = 0.0;
    var thetaLoc;

    var speed = 100;
    var direction = true;

    var colors = [
      vec4 (0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
      vec4 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), //blue
      vec4 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), //green
      vec4 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) //black
    ];


    window.onload = function init()
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

        gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
        if (!gl) alert("WebGL 2.0 isn't available");

    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram( program );

    var vertices = [
        vec2(-.5,  -.5),
        vec2(0,  .5),
        vec2(.5,  -.5)
    ];

 


    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "aPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uTheta");

    var colorLoc=gl.getAttribLocation(program, "fcolor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLoc, 4, gl.Float, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLoc)

    colors=gl.getUniformLocation(program, "color_changer");
    

    // Initialize event handlers

    document.getElementById("slider").onchange = function(event) {
        speed = 100 - event.target.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("Direction").onclick = function (event) {
        direction = !direction;
    };   

    document.getElementById("Controls").onclick = function( event) {
        switch(event.target.index) {
          case 0:
            direction = !direction;
            break;

         case 1:
            speed /= 2.0;
            break;

         case 2:
            speed *= 2.0;
            break;  
        
         case 3:
            colors[1][0][0][1];
            break;
        
        case 4:
          colors[0][0][1][1];
          break;
        
        case 5:
          colors[1][1][1][1];
          break;
       }
    };

    window.onkeydown = function(event) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        switch( key ) {
          case '1':
            direction = !direction;
            break;

          case '2':
            speed /= 2.0;
            break;

            case '3':
            speed *= 2.0;
            break; 

            case '4':
              colors[1][0][0][1];
              break;
          
          case '5':
            colors[0][0][1][1];
            break;
          
          case '6':
            colors[1][1][1][1];
            break;
        }
    };

    render(); 
    }; 



    function render()
   {
       gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

       theta += (direction ? 0.1 : -0.1);
       gl.uniform1f(thetaLoc, theta);

       gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

       setTimeout(
           function () {requestAnimationFrame(render);},
        speed, colors
         );
      }

I want the color to change when clicking on the associated menu controls.
I tried changing to different return statements in the switch function, but the color is still not functioning correctly. All other menu clicks work except for color. Please advise.

(1) Not sure what colors[1][0][0][1]; is supposed to achieve. For example, why can't it just be colors[1];, if you want the second vec3 color in the array? (2) What happens if you don't use an Array and just instead keep each color as a separate NAMED variable that you can later access within your Switch/Case statement? Does it now do the expected color change?
